# Matlab - convert decimal datetime to string format

Tags: matlab, datetime

I am trying to convert the following datetime into string format in Matlab.

20121003.03

It corresponds to 3rd Oct 2012, 03:00am. Any ideas?

Comment: What format is it in now? Is 20121003.03 stored as a floating point number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a custom input format when creating a `datetime` object. Your question seems to indicate that the object is already a datetime object, but at that point the problem is trivial, just call `datestr` on it (the last line of the script below). I'll assume here that the input is a floating point representation.

```
dval = 20121030.0330;

% Convert floating point number to a string
dstr = sprintf('%013.04f', dval);

% Convert string to a datetime object
dtime = datetime(dstr, 'InputFormat', 'yyyyMMdd.hhmm');

% Convert the datetime object into a formatted string
dstr2 = datestr(dtime);
```

Output:

```
dstr2 = '30-Oct-2012 03:00:00'
```

If you want an output format different than the default then you need to specify the output format of `datestr`. See the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datestr.html) for more information.

Comment: At the moment I'm reading tabular data in with load and it is stored as 'double'. Your suggestion worked perfectly for the example I gave. But it doesn't work for all my entries. For example, I also have: 20121003.033. I believe the data I have is every 30 mins.

Comment: modified based on comment.

Comment: Actually I think just having 'yyyyMMdd.hhmm' has fixed that